# jDialog disposed but still in jFrame.getOwnedWindows

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, dispose

I have a `JFrame` (EC_GUI.main) and then I create several `JDialog`s to which I add a `JPanel`, passing the `JFrame` as owner.

I am now in the process of detecting if any of these `JDialogs` are opened through the `jFrame.getOwnedWindows()`, since I can't get them through one of this

```
EC_GUI.main.getComponentCount() 1
javax.swing.JRootPane[,0,0,755x1005,layout=javax.swing.JRootPane$RootLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=16777673,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=]

EC_GUI.main.getRootPane().getComponentCount() 2
javax.swing.JPanel[null.glassPane,0,0,755x1005,hidden,layout=java.awt.FlowLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=16777217,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=]
javax.swing.JLayeredPane[null.layeredPane,0,0,755x1005,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=0,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,optimizedDrawingPossible=true]

EC_GUI.main.getContentPane().getComponentCount() 1
ec.gui.dialogs.template.EC_BorderPanel[,0,0,755x1005,layout=java.awt.BorderLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder@44e6097c,flags=9,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=]
```

But I do get them if I query the `ownedWindows`

```
EC_GUI.main.getOwnedWindows().length 1
ec.gui.dialogs.visivilityfield.EC_VrPresetDialog$1[dialog0,385,254,502x511,invalid,hidden,layout=java.awt.BorderLayout,MODELESS,title=Virtual Reality Presets,defaultCloseOperation=DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE,rootPane=javax.swing.JRootPane[,0,0,502x511,invalid,layout=javax.swing.JRootPane$RootLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=16777673,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=],rootPaneCheckingEnabled=true]
```

I noticed that even if I call `jDialog.dispose()` I still have a reference so if I open and close, let's say 3 times, one of my `JDialog`s, I get

```
EC_GUI.main.getOwnedWindows().length 3
ec.gui.dialogs.visivilityfield.EC_VrPresetDialog$1[dialog1,385,254,502x511,invalid,hidden,layout=java.awt.BorderLayout,MODELESS,title=Virtual Reality Presets,defaultCloseOperation=DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE,rootPane=javax.swing.JRootPane[,0,0,502x511,invalid,layout=javax.swing.JRootPane$RootLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=16777673,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=],rootPaneCheckingEnabled=true]
ec.gui.dialogs.visivilityfield.EC_VrPresetDialog$1[dialog2,385,254,502x511,invalid,hidden,layout=java.awt.BorderLayout,MODELESS,title=Virtual Reality Presets,defaultCloseOperation=DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE,rootPane=javax.swing.JRootPane[,0,0,502x511,invalid,layout=javax.swing.JRootPane$RootLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=16777673,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=],rootPaneCheckingEnabled=true]
ec.gui.dialogs.visivilityfield.EC_VrPresetDialog$1[dialog3,385,254,502x511,invalid,hidden,layout=java.awt.BorderLayout,MODELESS,title=Virtual Reality Presets,defaultCloseOperation=DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE,rootPane=javax.swing.JRootPane[,0,0,502x511,invalid,layout=javax.swing.JRootPane$RootLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=16777673,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=],rootPaneCheckingEnabled=true]
```

Is this normal?

Comment: You are mixing `JPanel`s with `JDialogs`, rewrite the question to make it clear. Also, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @user1803551 ok, gimme 5m

Comment: You read through the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#dispose()) you will not that, when configured correctly, `dispose` will release the native resources that the window is using, this does not "dispose" of the object, you can reshow the window by calling `setVisble`.  You could check the `isDisplayable` or the more reliable `isVisible` option...

Comment: @user1803551, sorry but the MCVE takes more time than I thought.. anyway you were right, I mixed them, sorry. Basically what the program is doing is instantiating a new jDialog, then a new jPanel and add the jPanel to the jDialog. The jDialog is created by passing the jFrame as owner, and when the jDialog is closed, the dispose() on the jDialog is called. So jPanel plays no role in this.

Comment: @MadProgrammer, I noticed that after some time the first jDialogs get cleared.. I guess because of the Garbage Collector..I tried to add some System.gc() calls and it effectively cleans some instances of the jDialogs but not all of them, it always left one instance.. Anyway, your suggestion seems working, if you wanna answer I will accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You read through the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#dispose()) you will not that, when configured correctly, dispose will release the native resources that the window is using, this does not "dispose" of the object, you can re-show the window by calling setVisible.

You could check the `isDisplayable` (which will let you know if the window still has a reference to it's native peer) or the more reliable `isVisible` option...

If the dialog has no other strong references, it will, eventually be garbage collected.